# Handling turtle graphics in memory

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Is there a way to handle all of the things that are happening on my turtle window in the memory not displaying them on the screen?

Comment: I don’t think so, turtle isn’t intended for much more than an introduction to python graphics, I would suggest trying to use full pygame. Why do you want to use turtle?

Comment: Well, I've been working on my project based on Turtle for a long time now, so switching to pygame can be extremely difficult

Comment: Would you mind giving a little detail about what you are trying to accomplish? Are you integrating turtle with Tk? Also, I've been taking a Python bootcamp class and they are using Turtle for making games and doing some interesting things. Logo started off for kids but has taken on a life of its own in Python Turtle. There is a project called NetLogo (https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/) that is used for doing advanced simulations with Logo.

Comment: why do you want to do it in memory?

Comment: The answer is probably yes, provide a viable code example and we may be able to show you how.

Comment: What is this project? In my opinion, anything you can do in turtle is easier with pygame, and in pygame graphics are stored in memory by default until you tell it to put them on screen. I really would recommend swinging to pygame, staying in turtle will only make things harder for you later on. Turtle was made in the 1960s and the version of it present in python isn’t much different, it was never intended for any sophisticated graphics.